# Using node.js for-loop index in a coinbase-api callback function

Tags: node.js, coinbase-api

I am new to node.js and i am trying to make a simple script that will connect to the coinbase-api and get the current price of whatever markets are defined in the MARKET array.

The problem i am having is that the for-loop that iterates through the array is asynchronous and the callback function is not getting the correct index value for the array.

The two main solutions i have found are to use promises or force the loop to wait. I think i need to be using promises rather than forcing the for loop to wait but honestly i have failed to implement a solution either way. I have found may example of promises but i just cant seem to figure out how to implement them into my script. I would appreciate any help.

```
const coinbaseModule = require('coinbase-pro');

const COINBASE_URI = 'https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com';

// const MARKET = ['BTC-USD'];
const MARKET = ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-BTC'];

let askPrice = [null, null];

let averagePrice = [null, null];

let tickerCount = null;

const getCallback = (error, response, data) => 
{   
    if (error)
        return console.log(error);

    if ((data!=null) && (data.ask!=null) && (data.time!=null))
    {
        askPrice[tickerCount] = parseFloat(data.ask);
        
        if (averagePrice[tickerCount]===null)
        {
            averagePrice[tickerCount] = askPrice[tickerCount];
            console.log(MARKET[tickerCount] + " ask price: " + askPrice[tickerCount].toFixed(6));
        }
        else
        {   
            averagePrice[tickerCount] = (averagePrice[tickerCount] * 1000 + askPrice[tickerCount]) / 1001;
            console.log(MARKET[tickerCount] + " ask price: " + askPrice[tickerCount].toFixed(6) + " average price: "+ averagePrice[tickerCount].toFixed(6));
        }
    }
}

setInterval(() => 
{
    console.log('\n');
    publicClient = new coinbaseModule.PublicClient(COINBASE_URI); 

    for (tickerCount = 0; tickerCount < MARKET.length; tickerCount++) 
    {
        publicClient.getProductTicker(MARKET[tickerCount], getCallback);
    }

}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to use promises with trial and error from the helpful examples on the Mozilla Developer Network. I am sure i am making some mistakes but at least it is working now. Another little bonus is that i was able to remove a global.

```
const coinbaseModule = require('coinbase-pro');

const COINBASE_URI = 'https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com';

// const MARKET = ['BTC-USD'];
const MARKET = ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-BTC'];

let askPrice = [null, null];

let averagePrice = [null, null];

function getProductTicker(tickerCount) { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    publicClient.getProductTicker(MARKET[tickerCount],function callback(error, response, data){
        if (error)
            return console.log(error);

        if ((data!=null) && (data.ask!=null) && (data.time!=null))
        {
            askPrice[tickerCount] = parseFloat(data.ask);
            
            if (averagePrice[tickerCount]===null)
            {
                averagePrice[tickerCount] = askPrice[tickerCount];
                console.log(MARKET[tickerCount] + " ask price: " + askPrice[tickerCount].toFixed(6));
            }
            else
            {   
                averagePrice[tickerCount] = (averagePrice[tickerCount] * 1000 + askPrice[tickerCount]) / 1001;
                console.log(MARKET[tickerCount] + " ask price: " + askPrice[tickerCount].toFixed(6) + " average price: "+ averagePrice[tickerCount].toFixed(6));
            }
        resolve();
        }
    });
  });
}

setInterval( async () => 
{
    console.log('\n');
    publicClient = new coinbaseModule.PublicClient(COINBASE_URI); 

    for (var tickerCount = 0; tickerCount < MARKET.length; tickerCount++) 
    {
        await getProductTicker(tickerCount);
    }
}, 10000);
```